# Geometric sequence, finding two variables

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a geometric sequence $a=48, t_{n}= 16/27$ , and $S_n$= 976/27. Find n and r.

This is what i have tried:

$48, \ldots, 16/27$

One equation i got is: $16/27=48r^{n-1}$

I am not sure how to form another equation so that I can solve for the value n and r.

Comment: We'll need to know more about what you mean by $a$, $t_n$, and $S_n$.

Comment: a represents the first term in the geometric sequence.n represents the term number. tn represents the value of the term number. Sn represents the sum of the terms from 1 to n. r represents the common ratio between each term.

Comment: And the rest? What's $r$?

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is the first term in the series.  You have one equation.  The second you need is the partial sum of a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)  Do you see the $2$'s and $3$'s in the equation you cited? If you factor $976$ you get $61\cdot 2^4$  The fact that $61=2^6-3$ should be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Sum of first $n$ terms of geometric series is $\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$

$n^{th}$ term of a geoemetric series is $a.r^{n-1}$

you just need to use these two and nothing more than that..

you will have two equations and you have to find two unknowns $n$ and $r$...

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of $S_n$ as $a + ar + \cdots + ar^{n-1} = a\cdot\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$, assuming I have your notation right.